# Blender is not displaying anything when startup

Tags: workflow, windows, startup-file

So I got this new desktop PC (albeit second-hand), and I begun moving my old stuff from my laptop to here, including Blender 2.79. When starting up the program, I was greeted with something I call a *clear window.* No splash screen, no viewport, no UI, nothing. Moving the window felt laggy, and checking the Task Manager, it doesn't seem to eat any CPU usage, and I could say that it "crashed." I think that some very few people may have this exact problem, but trying to make this question ambiguous could be difficult.

So do you have any solutions, here? I don't have the slightest clue.

The hardware I'm using:
RAM: Nvidia Geforce 7900 GTX, 8GB RAM
Processor: AMD Athlon X4 610e 2.4ghz
Storage: 1TB HDD
OS: Window 10 Pro

[image: No, it's not the split moment of the window displaying the stuff, this is what it looks like.]

Answer (score 1):

Have you just moved the blender App folder to the new PC. Some settings might be needed in registry, so if you just moved the folder I would suggest a install of 2.79 from https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/